# Maclaurin's series for $\tan(x+x^2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I would like to find the Maclaurin's series for $\tan(x+x^2)$ stopped at $x_0^3$.

I tried with:
$$\tan(x+x^2)=1+\frac{1+2x_0}{\cos^2(x_0+x_0^2)}x+....,$$ but it seems like the derivation gets more complicated. I was wondering if there was a simpler way to solve the Maclaurin series. I was thinking about putting $t=x+x^2$, but it looks like wrong (why?).

**Update:**

I know that MacLaurin's expansion for tan(x): $$T(x) = x + \frac {1}{3}x^{3} + \frac { 2 } { 15 } x ^ { 5 } + \frac { 17 } { 315 } x ^ { 7 } + \ldots$$ But according to Mathematica, there should be  a $x^2$ for the MacLaurin series for $tan(x+x^2)$, which I couldn't understand.

Comment: If all you care about is the series and not its derivation, why not use Mathematica? I doubt there is any special trick for this.

Comment: Could you show me an example? Do you mean substituting $x_0$ with 0 and solving the derivatives?

Comment: @Hamed Because it is part of a question of my past exams, and we are not allowed to use Mathematica.

Comment: Setting $t=x+x^2$ in the series for $\tan{t}$ will work fine.  Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Apparently, the expansion is around an arbitrary point $x_0$ not zero.

Comment: @saulspatz Can you show me an example? I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute $x+x^2$ for $x$ in your formula of $T(x):$
$$T(x+x^2)=(x+x^2)+\frac13(x+x^2)^3+\cdots$$

Now you just have to expand and rearrange the terms.  Since you only need powers up through $x^3$, there no need to be concerned with the higher-degree terms in $T(x)$

Comment: Now I get it. Apparently, I had a lot of confusion in my mind. Thank you!